# Get variable in the service task without using forms

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

How to assign variable value in java delegate class?
I'm using postman for post request. I don't want to use forms. I want to get the variable in service task and save it in the database has it cannot be null . error comes in testing and it shows it cannot be null

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) get list of tasks:
GET /task?assignee=anAssignee

b) use task id to get process data:

GET **/task/aTaskId/variables**

See:

- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/get-query/
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/task/variables/get-task-variables/

Via Java API in the delegate code:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/delegation-code/

On the Java API outside a the delegate code via the TaskService:
https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.15/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html#getVariables-java.lang.String-java.util.Collection-

Comment: I want to assignee the value to a variable in the java class directly from the post call it gives an error as the value is null, I want to store that value in the database has the value cannot be null, can you show some exmples.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/ab290c041d794691c8f845f72072ffac94c1d90d/snippets/rest-service-task-spring/src/main/java/org/camunda/example/service/RestDelegate.java#L24

Comment: Check if vcUniqueTransID = (String) execution.getVariable("vcUniqueTransID") return null. If it does then you may not be submitting the data in the POST correctly. Please update your question with the details and I can update the answer

Comment: it is giving me the error in testing and not able to build the war file

Comment: You need to update your question and provide more details so somemone can help